# Competitive Intelligence Data

Tags: data-request

I am interested in finding out how many people visit a competitor's store each day. When I look at my competitors business on Google Maps it tells me how busy their store is each hour for every day of the week. This data doesn't include counts so there's no information to be gained from scraping the webpage.

I am open to paying for this kind of data and if there was other data available such as where these people come from, demographics etc. I would also be keen to get this.

Do you know if Google or Facebook have access to this data and whether they 'sell' such data?